# Получение коллекции значений свойств объекта

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Имеется следующий класс:

```
public class MyClass 
    { 
        public string StrProp1 {get; set;} 
        public string StrProp2 {get; set;} 
        public int IntProp {get; set;} 
        public DateTime? DTNullableProp {get; set;}
        public int? IntNullableProp {get; set;}

    }
```

Как получить коллекцию, например `Dictionary<string, string>` с парами "имя свойства" -> "значение". Значения, соответственно приводятся к типу string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
o.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(o)?.ToString());
```

Для C# 5, в котором нет `?.`, подойдёт чуть менее синтаксически красивый код:

```
o.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(
        p => p.Name,
        p => { var v = p.GetValue(o); return v == null ? null : v.ToString(); }
);
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/heZl2W